# Как сделать многопоточный парсер?

Tags: python, парсер, функции, xmlparser, multiprocessing

Задача моей программы в извлечении текстовой информации из сайта и запись ее в файл. URL адрес будет создаваться кусками, тип я бер из файла и добавляю его к ссылке. В итоге получается одна ссылка которую нужно парсить.

Я хочу сделать многопоточный парсер, но у меня просто нагружается процессор:

```
import requests
import time

from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing import Pool


urls1 = []
url1 = 'http://my_url/'
f = open("nicknames.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    x = line
    if line.find(':') >= 0:
        line=line[:line.find(':')]
    urls1.append(url1+line)
f.close()

def parse(url):
    r = requests.get()  # Я незнаю что здесь поставить
    R = r.text
    p0 = R.find('RAP:')
    R = R[p0:]
    p1 = R.find('</span>')
    p2 = R.find('>')
    R = R[p2+1:p1]      #  это я без бьютифул супа парсю штмл
    #  print(R)
    if len(R[2:]) > 0:
        normal.append(x+' '+R[2:]+'$')
    else:
        err.append(x+' '+R[2:])
    time.sleep(1)

with Pool(4) as p:
    p.map(parse, urls1)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

e = open('error.txt', 'w')
e.write(err)
e.close()
m = open('normal.txt', 'w')
m.write(normal)
m.close()
```

Я добавляю все ссылки которые нужно будет парсить в массив, чтобы использовать функцию `map`, но у меня оно не работает, не понимаю - почему?

Comment: проблема в "Я незнаю что здесь поставить" ?

Comment: Я знаю что туда нужно урл, но как какой, там или сразу все, я не знаю как сделать чтобы из всех урл туда добавлялся только один из массива

Comment: Распаралеливание процесса делается по стандартной схеме: берется блок "входных" данных, блок бьётся на несколькоко частей по колличеству threads. После завершения работы всех threads полученый результат сшивается. Данная задача усложняется тем, что границы блоков прийдется выравнять по границам тега xml анализируя часть xml, а не весь, т.к. тогда 
распаралеливание теряет смысл. Вторая сложность - сшить полученый результат в одно. Как это реализовать - затрудняюсь ответить. Это хорошая тема диплома, а не ответа на SO.

Comment: Если у вас просто тупо распаралеленый поиск определенных данных - то всё чуть проще - бьёте на блоки, сдвигаете границы блоков - и запускаете поиск внутри блоков, с возможность заглянуть на n-байтов за пределы границы.